# SimGrid. Asynchronous communications and failing links

Tags: java, simgrid

Simulation has one `master` and seven `workers`. When workers end to execute data, they `dsend` `messageTasks` to `master` about completion of execution.

```
 getHost().setProperty("busy", "no");
 ReleaseTask releaseTask = new ReleaseTask(getHost().getName());
 releaseTask.dsend("Master");
```

The link connects `worker1` and `master` is broken. It is link1.fail file.

```
PERIODICITY 2
0 1
1 0
```

I expected that only one `releaseTask` (from worker1) can't reach `master`. But, unfortunately, no `releaseTasks` (from other workers) achieve `master`. This error-warning appears:

```
[13.059397] /builds/workspace/SimGrid-Multi/build_mode/Debug/node/simgrid-ubuntu-trusty-64/build/SimGrid-3.13/src/simix/smx_global.cpp:554: [simix_kernel/CRITICAL] Oops ! Deadlock or code not perfectly clean.
[13.059397] [simix_kernel/INFO] 16 processes are still running, waiting for something.
```

Master receive `task` in such way:

```
Task listenTask = Task.receive("Master");
```

When link connects `worker1` and `master` isn't broken, all simulation works fine.

How can I avoid this problem?

**UPDATED**

My `platform.xml` file:

`<link id="0_11" state_file="linkfailures/0_11.fail" bandwidth="3.430125Bps" latency="4.669142ms"/>`

`0_11.fail` file:

```
PERIODICITY 2
0 1
1 0
```

Worker starts to `dsend` a `MessageTask` to master at 6.94 s. `MessageTask` transmission time is 0.07 sec. But at 7.00 s. the link which connects master and worker starts to be broken. I guess master continues timeless "receiving" data and error occurs. But how to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send your data with `dsend`, it only means that you don't care of whether the receiver gets it or whether an error occurs. It does not make the communication more robust (nor less robust either).

You updated your question, giving two possible outcomes to your simulation. Sometimes you say that no communication makes it to master and that the simulation ends when SimGrid reports a deadlock (`16 processes are still running, waiting for something`), and sometimes you report a that a `TransferFailureError` is occurring. But actually, that's exactly what is expected in your case, if I'm right.

Here is what happens:

- you send a message with `dsend`
- the message get lost because the link fails. Nope, it does not take for ever to deliver because the link fails, it just disappear immediately.

At this point there is two possible outcomes, depending on whether the link fails before or after the communication starts (before or after the receiver posts its `recv`).

- If the link fails **before** the time where the receiver (the master in your case, it seems) posts its `recv` request, then the failure will not be noticed. Indeed,  there is no receiver yet to inform and the sender said that it does not care about the communication outcome, by using a `dsend`.
- If the link fails **after** the time where the receiver posts its request, then the sender does not notice anything (because of the `dsend`), and the receiver gets a `TransferFailureException` on its receive action. So the failing communication is killing someone even if you sent it with dsend, but actually that's the master who dies. That is why the other slaves cannot communicate with the master: he got an uncatched exception while receiving something from the fishy host.

If you want the sender to notice that your message did not went through (to resend it maybe), then you don't want to use `dsend` but `isend` (for an asynchronous communication) or `send` (for a blocking communication). And the sender has to pay attention for the status of the communication.

If you want your message to be really delayed but not destroyed, then try changing the bandwidth of the link to 0 for a while (using `availability_file` instead if `state_file`).

If you want your receiver to survive such communication issue, just catch the exception it gets.